# Rails 3.2 link_to url from database without quotes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Please help... :) Working on this for a couple of days now

I have a submittal database with stored url's to manufacturer installation instructions generally in PDF formats. I don't want to use the default to_path because I'll have to store the documents locally on my server. Here's the snippet of code that I'm using to pull the url path from my database. As you can see below without the path_to rails wants to turn the url into a path (see error below). I tried adding quotes but then rails doesn't read the code correctly. I've read about helpers but haven't gotten them to work.

```
<%= @wf_room.wf_lights.pluck(:typemark).count %> <%= link_to @wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:typemark).uniq, @wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:url).uniq %>
```

error:
undefined method `http://www.sistemalux.com/en/files/ficheproduit/7050_Sliver_wall(13).pdf_path' for #<#:0x0000000404bad8>

Comment: What's the individual outputs of `@wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:typemark).uniq` and `@wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:url).uniq`?

Comment: @wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:typemark).uniq is L40 and @wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:url).uniq is (url link) http://www.sistemalux.com/en/files/ficheproduit/7050_Sliver_wall(13).pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried string interpolation?

```
<%= link_to @wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:typemark).uniq.first, "#{@wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:url).uniq.first}" %>
```

(I added first method because won't they the current methods return arrays?)

Comment: Thanks! This solution works! So why the .first? I tried the same thing without the .first and rails errors... "No route matches [GET] "/wf_rooms/"

Comment: It's because '@wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:typemark).uniq' returns an array (I'm guessing with only the object you wanted), what .first did was pick the first object in the array and returned that object